# Redshift in gnome on wayland on Debian

Tags: debian, gnome, wayland

As you may know, Wayland compositors can control and change the screen gamma curve but currently there's no third-party application which can do it; this means, at least in wayland, no redshift or flux. Yesterday I've found this [article](http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/redshift-functionality-on-fedora-25-gnome-wayland-yes-its-possible) explaining that some user has patched gnome settings daemon to make redshift work in Gnome on Wayland but this particular version can work on Fedora or Arch. I've tried it in Arch and it works but Arch is my test machine, I'm not so much used to Arch, yet.

So, my question is:
Since in the git repo of the patched gst for Arch there's only the `PKGBUILD` file, while in the repo of the `gnome-shell` extension there is the patch to apply, is there a way to reproduce all this stuff on debian? That is, is there a way to make a `.deb` package out of the pkgbuild or can somebody explain me how to patch gst?

I hope I made myself as clear as possible.

Useful link:

[aur package of gnome-shell-extension-redshift-native](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gnome-settings-daemon-redshift/)

Comment: FYI [Gnome v3.24](https://www.gnome.org/news/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released/) now has this feature built-in.

Comment: @rugk still waiting gnome 3.24 on Debian -.-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the sources of `gnome-settings-daemon` whith `apt-get source` command.

You can then add the patches to the `debian/patches` directory (and add the file name of the patch to `debian/patches/series`)

You need to bump the version in the `debian/changelog` file (ie. `dch -llocal`).

And then rebuild the package with `dpkg-buildpackage -b`

That should produce .deb files

Comment: Just this? On my way!

Comment: I have installed all the needed dependencies and did all you said but I got this error three times `dpkg-deb: error: unable to parse timestamp '': Success
dpkg-deb: error: unable to parse timestamp '': Success
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb --build debian/gnome-settings-daemon-dev .. returned exit code 2
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb -z1 -Zxz -Sextreme --build debian/.debhelper/gnome-settings-daemon/dbgsym-root .. returned exit code 2
debian/rules:8: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
`

Comment: the `debian/changelog` is properly formatted?

Comment: yes, I believe so. I just copied the last entry and modified the version number and the date/time like this `Mon, 12 Dec 2016 14:39:33 +0200`

Comment: Ok, now I have this `dpkg-source: error: LC_ALL=C patch -t -F 0 -N -p1 -u -V never -E -b -B .pc/gsd-master-color-Add-ability-to-change-the-color-temperature-of.patch/ --reject-file=- < gnome-settings-daemon-3.22.1.orig.oBqZLh/debian/patches/gsd-master-color-Add-ability-to-change-the-color-temperature-of.patch gave error exit status 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b gnome-settings-daemon-3.22.1 gave error exit status 2` Is there somthing wrong with the patch files maybe?

Comment: fond the problem: there are two patch files, one for version 3.22.1 of gsd and one for the current git master branch, so I just need to use the correct one and not both

Comment: Final comment: I did it, but I have to give the command `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us` because I don't have a validated gpg key. However, I finally have redshift working on wayland :D